# PHP prevent extra empty line when writing text to file

Tags: php, arrays, text, line

I'm having a small issue regarding a foreach() loop and writing an array to a text file within.
The loop gives me the format in the file that I want but it also adds (as I was told) an unwanted empty line at the end of the file.

Here is my piece of code:

```
foreach($data_arr as $data => $input)
{ fwrite($fh, $data . ":" . $input . "\n") or die("something went wrong here"); }
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and not add the \n when it reaches the end of the array?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not use `file_put_contents`?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if current index is the last one, then eventually add "\n" to the string

```
$last_index = count($data_arr)-1;

foreach ($data_arr as $data => $input)
{ 
    $string = $data . ":" . $input;
    if ($data != $last_index) 
    {
        $string .= "\n";
    }
    
    fwrite($fh, $string) or die("something went wrong here"); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to check the difference between my piece and yours?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
$data_array = ['c', 'h', "hf"];
$last = count($data_array) - 1; #size of the array

foreach($data_array as $data => $input)
{ 
  $separator = $data == $last ? "" : "\n"; #if is last, then seperator isn't a back to line
  fwrite($fh, $data . ":" . $input . $separator);
}
```

Comment: I am trying your solution because it is compact and elegant... and on its own it seems to work.. however.. when I add it to my code it still adds an extra line in the text file underneath :/ Only thing I changed where the variable names back to the original ones. Also.. I am using an associative array with self named keys.. but that can't be why it doesn't work properly, right?

Comment: Can you add your full code ? From the `fopen` to the end including your data ? (or at least, a sample of it)

Comment: Never mind.. I changed your code to include an associative array and it also added an extra blank line to the text file...

Answer (score 0):

Determining whether you are doing something for the *last* time, is cumbersome - for starters, you need to *count* your items, and then you need a loop index to compare to that count …

Much easier to determine, whether you are doing something for the *first* time. So just reverse your logic here - do not try to output “all lines, followed by a newline each, except the last one”, but instead, output “all lines *preceded by* a newline each, except the *first* one.”

You could use a simple boolean flag for that:

```
$is_first_line = true;
foreach($data_arr as $data => $input) {
  fwrite($fh, ($is_first_line ? "" : "\n") . $data . ":" . $input);
  $is_first_line = false;
}
```

Or you just append a variable before the line data all the time - and simply make that variable “empty” on the first iteration, and then fill it with a newline character for all the following ones:

```
$prefix = "";
foreach($data_arr as $data => $input) {
  fwrite($fh, $prefix . $data . ":" . $input);
  $prefix = "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems to work even with an associative array (whereas the other solutions somehow did not)!